# Yii Framework : Change log layout

Tags: php, yii

I am using the yii log facility to log some important events. Does any one has an idea how change the log layout in yii ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend CFileLogRoute and rewrite formatLogMessage method. Example:

```
class YourFileLogRoute extends CFileLogRoute
{

    ...

    /**
     * Formats a log message given different fields.
     * @param string $message message content
     * @param integer $level message level
     * @param string $category message category
     * @param integer $time timestamp
     * @return string formatted message
     */
    protected function formatLogMessage($message, $level = 'I', $category = null, $time = null)
    {
        if ($time === null)
            $time = time();

        $level = strtoupper($level[0]);

        return @date( 'M d H:i:s', $time ) . ' [' . sprintf( '%-30s', $category ) . '] ' . ': <' . $level . '> ' . $message . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```